# ddev start - failed to load any docker-compose.*y*l files

Tags: docker-compose, ddev

I'm trying to work on a project that other colleagues were able to set up. My issues starts when I do ddev config and after that ddev start, the project seems to not give any issue until it throws an error like this:

> Failed to start my-project: failed to load any docker-compose.*y*l files:

The file docker-compose.*y*l is inside the project/.ddev folder. Tried to reinstall, update, rollback version, even using the same configs as my colleagues and I always get the same error.

Here's an ls -l of the file it should find.

> -rw-r--r--@ 1 lukemk  staff  5591 Jan 27 16:36 .ddev/docker-compose.yaml

Related issues I could find didn't have any relation with mine. All other projects seems to work properly without similar issues.

I'm running everything on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2.

ddev version output:

> DDEV-Local version      v1.12.2                                 commit
>   v1.12.2                                 db
>   drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.2:v1.12.0 dba
>   drud/phpmyadmin:v1.12.0                 ddev-ssh-agent
>   drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.12.0             docker
>   19.03.5                                 docker-compose          1.25.2                                  os                      darwin                                  router
>   drud/ddev-router:v1.12.0                web
>   drud/ddev-webserver:v1.12.2

I tried to remove the project and rebuild it again, reinstalled, ddev, docker and everything stills the same. Does someone why docker asks for that file which is in its place?
How can I fix it?

**Edit:**
As rfay said, I had my ddev path set with glob characters. So my project was trying to deploy in something like this:
"/Users/llucmarques/PhpstormProjects/project/myproject [Local]/project-relaunch"

And it was fixed by renaming it to:
/Users/llucmarques/PhpstormProjects/project/myproject_Local/project-relaunch

rfay added a new commit for ddev that will display a message in case you are using glob characters.

Comment: Answered in both https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2049 and TYPO3 slack. Let's go ahead and continue in TYPO3 slack for now. We'll get it going!

Comment: Oh and Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This turned out to be use of glob characters ("[]" in this case) that made it impossible to search for docker*.y*ml.  It's being tracked in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out issue was being cause by glob characters. @rfay posted a new commit to display a proper error due the use of glob characters in the project path. Tacked in ddev's github:

https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2049